# Remove Nth Node From End of List

Tags: c++, interview-questions, linked-list

Given a linked list, remove the nth node from the end of list and return its head.

For example,

> Given linked list: 1->2->3->4->5, and n = 2.
>
> After removing the second node from the end, the linked list
>   becomes 1->2->3->5.
>
> ```
> ListNode *removeNthFromEnd(ListNode *head, int n) {
>     // Start typing your C/C++ solution below
>     // DO NOT write int main() function
>     if (head == NULL) {
>       return NULL;
>     }
>
>     ListNode *pre, *cur;
>     pre = cur = head;
>     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
>       pre = pre->next;
>     }
>
>     while (pre != NULL && pre->next != NULL) {
>       cur = cur->next;
>       pre = pre->next;
>     }
>
>   //mistake
>   //if (cur == head) {
>   // I use the above line to check if it's the first node to be deleted, 
>   // there is a problem for this case: list: 1->2, n : 1
>     if (pre == NULL) {
>       ListNode *newHead = head->next;
>       delete head;
>       return newHead;
>     }
>     else {
>       ListNode *tmp = cur->next;
>       cur->next = tmp->next;
>       delete tmp;
>       return head;
>     }        
> }
> ```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not clear whether it's asking for code to be written; also the code being embedded in a block quote makes it looks like it's not the OP's code.

Comment: @retailcoder: Based on the tag, I assume this was straight from the interviewer.  But I cannot tell for sure, so I agree with your close reason.

Answer (score 1):

Your function fails if `n` is 0 or greater than the list size.

Also, I prefer to see one variable defined per-line:

```
ListNode *pre = head;
ListNode *cur = head;
```

And the opening brace belongs in column 0 (I guess you don't agree, but there are - or were anyway - tools that rely on this).

An alternative implementation might use a function to find the number of entries in the list and another to return a specified entry (size - n - 1, in this case). Then once you've checked that 0 < n <= size, the main function is simple - but no better than yours :-)

BTW, `delete` is C++, not C

Comment: If there are tools that rely on the code being formatted in non-K&R-style, then it's not the code that is wrong, it is the tools. Both *The C Programming Language* and *The C++ Programming Language* books use this style. Admittedly not for functions, but it's still perfectly valid C and C++. Which tools rely on the opening brace being in column 0?